# wordpress blog homepage customization

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

please don't give a negative feed like always and instead tell me the mistake.

I have a blog.

can i make the homepage display a summary of an article instead of the whole article?

if yes then where or how can i do it?

Comment: You can fetch the sumary textarea with [`get_the_excerpt(POSTID)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) or you can get the content and limit the amount of words of the content with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this pre-set in one of my WordPress sites. Here is what this looks like and it is in Appearance/Editor/Posts Page (home.php)

```
    <div class="post-content">
        <?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
        <?php echo wp_trim_words(strip_tags($content), 30); ?>
    </div>

<a class="blog-post-read-more" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_theme_mod( 'relia_blog_read_more', __( 'Read More', 'relia' ) ) ); ?></a>

   </div>
```

So what this does is it will strip the words up to 30, [wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words). And below that is the how to insert Read More.

Here are some links for you to check out:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt
https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Answer (score 1):

```
Create one custom template that template you can assign your home page

    /*
    Template Name: Blog
    */
        query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) ) );

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format());  ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
wp_reset_postdata();
```